# Android - Updating list with Volley

Tags: android, list, android-volley

I am developing a DialogFragments with radius options. This options are loaded from a remote database and I want to save this in my list ***`players`***. I am using Volley to connect with my remote database and loaded the players.

My problem is that the list players **never is updated**. The method `Accion.attendancesPlayerToGame` works perfectly, but after in the line

`final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[players.size()]` , `players.size` always is equal to zero.
When I put a breakpoint inside the method *Acciones.attendancesPlayerToGame*, if the list is modified. What it is the problem? Thanks for your help.

**DialogFragment**

```
  public AlertDialog createRadioListDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    String gameID= getArguments().getString("gameID");

    List<JugadorView> players=new ArrayList<JugadorView>();
    Acciones.attendancesPlayerToGame(gameID, getContext(),players);
    final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[players.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i< players.size();i ++){
        String nombre= players.get(i).nombre;
        String apellidos = players.get(i).apellidos;
        String nombreComplet = nombre + " " + apellidos;
        items[i] = nombreComplet;
    }



more code
    }
```

**attendancesPlayerToGame**

```
public static void attendancesPlayerToGame(final String idGame,final Context context, final List<JugadorView> jugadorViewList) {
    final String URLLISTGROUP = "http://www.myweb.com/app/file.php";
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLLISTGROUP,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            String emailJugador = jsonObject.getString("emailJugador");
                            String nombreJugador = jsonObject.getString("nombreJugador");
                            String apellidosJugador = jsonObject.getString("apellidosJugador");
                            String jugadorId = jsonObject.getStri

ng("jugadorID");


                                JugadorView jugadorView = new JugadorView(nombreJugador, apellidosJugador, emailJugador, jugadorId);

                                jugadorViewList.add(jugadorView);



                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("idGame", idGame);

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jugadorViewList.add(jugadorView);
```

//after this line u need update ur adapter of this list ==> jugadorViewList. U need something like this.

```
adapterOfJugadorList.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your answer, but does not work. I tried your answer, but it does not work. I really do not need any adapter, I just want my List `<JugadorView> player` is updated after calling the method `Accion.attendancesPlayerToGame`.

Comment: if u have a list it´s a must to have an adapter, it how android works.... if u do not have an adapter, u can try this way.
jugadorViewList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();